# JsGrid skip a row

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

I have a JsGrid implementation. In which I use some itemtemplates for calculations like:

```
 itemTemplate: function(value, item) {
      Total = Total + (item.SomeValue - item.SomeOtherValue);
          return(Total);
      }
```

Sometimes "Total" is empty. in that case I want to skip the complete row.
Is there any way to do that?
Now I end up with a lot of empty rows.

Thanks, Mike

Comment: if (!total) { break; }

It depends on how you're adding rows, is this function just called for each new row?

Comment: I use the "Standard" JsGrid library. Do not exactly know how rows are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itemTemplate` is used for updating the cell in the row. If you want to manipulate row then you have to use callback function `rowRenderer`.

```
rowRenderer: function(item,itemIndex){
    if('condition_to_skip_row'){ return null;}
    return '<h1>1<h1>';
}
```

For reference follow the jqGrid documentation - http://js-grid.com/docs/#configuration